# Android: How to record video with a custom audio track?

Tags: android, audio-recording, video-recording

I've been asked to make a 'dubsmash' alike app, where you record a video but with a music over it.
So the video file needs to have the custom audio track embeded.
Is it possible?
(I'm noob with android :p )
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have not "demonstrated" any effort of your own, so I should not answer this as per rules, but here goes : Yes, it is possible. Read this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html

FYI : The code in the example works perfectly, so please don't ask for any other sample

Comment: Thanks. I've searched for it, but didn't know the name of that class.